# div.d precision in MIPS

Tags: assembly, double, mips, mars-simulator

```
 .data
input1: .asciiz "Please enter what unit do you want to convert it into: \n" 
ask:    .asciiz "Please enter the length\n"
mmtocm: .double 10.0
test:   .double 100.0
result: .asciiz "The result is: %.2f\n"

.text
MAIN:
    # print prompt
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ask
    syscall
    
    # read length
    li $v0, 7 
    syscall
    
    #divide length by mmtocm and store result in $f12
    l.d $f4, mmtocm
    div.d $f12, $f0, $f4
    
    # print result
    #li $v0, 3
        la $a0, result
        li $v0, 3
        syscall
    
    
Exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

so heres is my instruction when i input 20 , it will print 2.0 which is fine , but when i input 20.3, it will input 2.03000000000002 , and i want the answer up to 2 deciamal only, this only happen when i use div.d instruction when is use mul.d for instace , and i input 20.3 it will give me 203.0 , and also theres certain number that work e.g , 10.5 , and it will give me 1.05 which is correct whcih also fine , anyone can help , thank you in advance

i expect to get 2.03 as an answer when in input 20.3

Comment: Yes, floating point is imprecise, especially with decimal values. There's no easy way to format floats with MARS or QtSPIM. For one, there's no `printf` function (so no `%.2f`) ; for another, while we can print a floating point number to the console, we cannot print a float to a string or to a file, so we cannot even post process the floating point number as a text string, say to remove digits and then display. Lastly, converting floating point number to a string yourself (as in writing one's own `printf`) is an option, but this is *very* complicated in the general case.

Comment: If you can narrow your use-case to a small-ish input range, some solutions might present.

Comment: If you don't need to support large numbers, one way is to multiply by 100 and convert to integer (ideally with rounding instead of truncation).  Then print `n/100`, a decimal point, and `n%100`.  But that of course fails for inputs like 2030000000000 which a `double` can hold exactly but which are larger than 2^31-1

Comment: Unfortunately this is a limitation of the IEEE 754 standard. It has no concept of significant digits (the number of decimal places in the number's base ten representation isn't encoded at all.)